# Drag and Drop control from toolbox not working

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, user-controls, toolbox

In **windows form application**, i created a usercontrol page. Here, I need to add a myowncontrol from tool box.

I just added myowncontrol in the tool box. by the way of browsing dll and placed it in tool box.

Here, when i drag and drop any one of default control, which  can easily dragged and placed in the usercontrol page. But when i try to drag and drop  myowncontrol into  usercontrol page , its not working.

Can't able to drag and drop.
(i mean i can pick the control from the tool box but i can't able to place it where i want)

what is the problem in my area?

Comment: its worked me..:) i just clean and rebuild the project and then add the control from tool box .

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit that this does not directly answer your question, but I am wondering if you have tried to programmatically add the control to a Form?  You would need to add a reference to the DLL that contains the UserControl and then do something similar to below in your source code.

```
var myCtrl = new MyControl(); //your UserControl class here
myCtrl.Location = new Point(25,25); //give it a location
this.Controls.Add(myCtrl); //add it
```

Also another thought... Are you sure that it's not really being added and it's just not visible?  For a Form or UserControl in the Visual Studio **Properties** Window there is a drop-down at the top which contains all the controls that have been added.

[image: http://functionx.com/vcsharp/windows/propwnd/combobox1.gif]

Comment: thanks for your  reply, you mean in the properties area shows the control contained by the form.. fine, i can able to drag and drop anyother default coltrols from the tool box, But can't able to drag and drop my own control from the tool box. Why is the problem over here while drag and droping own control?

Comment: and one more thing , In visual studio which contains **Document Outline** view(**Ctrl + Alt + T**). which shows the particular form contains what are all the controls are existing in the form. But which is also doesn't shows added own control